# Why will gem build .gemspec succeed when the dependency gem(s) is not installed yet

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I tried to build a local gem and was surprised to find that even the dependency gems were not installed I can still run `gem build .gemspec` successfully.

For example, my `.gemspec` has declared the following dependency and I am sure they are not installed yet. But `gem build` succeeded and only after I run `gem install` to install my local gem will those gems be installed as well.

```
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "terminal-notifier-guard"
  spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "~> 4.2.0"
```

From c/c++ background, I find that is a bit confusing. I know ruby is interpreted/dynamic (whatever that means) language, the script will be interpreted when I actually run it. But what does `gem build .gemspec` build then? What criteria will it use to determine the build is successful (e.g. except for syntax error in codes)?

Answer (score 0):

Dependent gems are installed as remote dependency and are installed when the gem is being installed or during bundle in case of rails. You cannot make it local dependent since it cannot be accessed by others.So your mention of

```
 spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "~> 4.2.0"
```

in .gemspec file is correct.

**.gemspec:** Gem build information is stored here. It is a standard format for describing all of the information that gets packed with gems then deployed to rubygems.org.

> gem build hola.gemspec

It's just used to build and you need to run gem install to test it.